# Store cookie with swipe to delete jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, cookies, cordova, jquery-cookie

I have a phonegap app I'm utilising jquery mobile to display a list which I want users to be able to swipe options out to hide them - I am using this: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0/docs/examples/swipe/swipe-list.html#demo-page

I need to have the app remember the users deletions if they were to reload the page - I'm guessing a cookie would be required however with my limited JS knowledge I'm struggling to write a cookie for the swipe to delete functions! Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use localStorage to store an array of your deleted items objects.  Use JSON.stringify to convert the array to string before storing:

```
var delItems= [];
delItems.push({id:"1",title:"title1"});
delItems.push({id:"2",title:"title2"});
delItems.push({id:"3",title:"title3"});

localStorage.setItem('deletedItems', JSON.stringify(delItems));
```

Retrieve list from storage:

```
var delItems = JSON.parse(localStorage["deletedItems"]);
```

Here is an article with examples where localStorage is extended to add setArray and getArray prototypes: http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2013/05/phonegap-saving-arrays-in-local-storage/

Comment: Could you please give an example using the source of the swipe demo of how to incorporate the array with the list items? - I'm guessing we'd use the variable listitem but need hand holding to get started

Comment: Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/UF47n/  Using the example, when user confirms delete I am saving the TOPIC to delItems array and localStorage.  When the form loads, if localStorage has that variable, I loop through each item on the list and if its TOPIC is in the array I remove it.  Try it by deleting an item and then hit RUN at top of screen again. In real-life you might be dynamically loading a list from an AJAX call or server side DB, etc.  In that case you need to use what makes your list item unique (e.g. ID).

Comment: awesome; thanks. How would I create a function to restore back (i.e. delete the cookie?) as I can't set the array back to 0?

Comment: Use removeItem:  localStorage.removeItem("deletedItems");, then refresh the page.